# bash "pass through" script for android build, space issue

Tags: bash, parameters, escaping

I have an android build i need to customize,
the question is ehre and not in stackoverflow because my issue wis with bash.
I wrote a script:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
params=$@
if [ "$#" -ge "2" ]; then
    params=$1
    shift
    params="$params --custom-package com.some.package"
    while [ "$#" -gt "0" ]; do
        temp=$1
        echo $1 | grep ' ' > /dev/null
        if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
            temp=\"$1\"
        fi
        params="$params $temp"
        shift
    done

fi
path=$(echo $0|xargs dirname)
echo $params
$path/aapt-orig $params
```

the script suppose to take the parameters it got, add --custom-package com.some.package parameter and keep the rest of the params, the first ($1) param is the action so i need to keep it first.

The problem is with spaces in directory names './my android dir/' for example.
if i just pass the parameter through:
param ="$param $1"; shit; if i have spaces in the name it doesn't work cause the new param is not escaped(with "), if i use the code above it still doesn't work because for some reason bash ignores the " char and still consider the space in the middle as a separate parameter! here is the output from the run: './aapt action "/Users/bankleumi/some dir/" another_param'

```
'[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ temp='"/Users/bankleumi/some dir/"'
+ params='action --custom-package com.leumi.leumiwallet "/Users/bankleumi/some dir/"'
+ shift
+ '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
+ temp=another_param
+ echo another_param
+ grep ' '
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ params='action --custom-package com.leumi.leumiwallet "/Users/bankleumi/some dir/" another_param'
+ shift
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
path=$(echo $0|xargs dirname)
echo $0|xargs dirname
++ echo ./aapt
++ xargs dirname
+ path=.
echo $params
+ echo action --custom-package com.leumi.leumiwallet '"/Users/bankleumi/some' 'dir/"' another_param
action --custom-package com.leumi.leumiwallet "/Users/bankleumi/some dir/" another_param
$path/aapt-orig $params
+ ./aapt-orig action --custom-package com.leumi.leumiwallet '"/Users/bankleumi/some' 'dir/"' another_param
```

As you can see in the end in the printing of the echo bash consider the string   "/Users/bankleumi/some dir" as two strings even though there are \" integrated IN the string!
how can i make bash leave the space alone? ( i tried playing with IFS and it didn't work either...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mess with re-quoting, it won't work due to the way sh/bash use word-splitting on variables -- that is, they split the value *without* first considering the quotes in the value.

You could get around that by using `eval "$path/aapt-orig $params"`...

But Bash has arrays, use them instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
args=()
args+=("$1"); shift
args+=(--custom-package com.leumi.leumiwallet)
for arg in "$@"; do
    args+=("$arg")
done
exec "$(dirname "$0")/aapt-orig" "${args[@]}"
```

**Or even simpler:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec "${0%/*}/aapt-orig" "$1" --custom-package com.leumi.leumiwallet "${@:2}"
```

Comment: Side note: `echo $0 | xargs dirname`? *Really?*

Comment: For some reason which I am sure @grawity will understand better than I, using double quotes also works: `./aapt action ""/Users/bankleumi/some dir/"" another_param`

Comment: @terdon: I'm not sure *how* that would work. After bash's unquoting, `""foo bar"" baz` is exactly the same as `foo bar baz`, and aapt receives it as three single-word arguments.

Comment: No idea, @grawity, just tried it on a whim and it worked. I used the script in the OP and just double quoted the CLI argument as shown above. The relevant output was: `+ echo action --custom-package com.some.package /Users/bankleumi/some dir/ another_param`. Bash version: `GNU bash, version 4.2.36(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 1):

This should work with more shells, and may be easier to understand:

```
#!/bin/sh
first="$1"; shift;
exec "`dirname '$0'`/aapt-orig" "$first" --custom-package com.foo.bar "$@";
```

Note that it works because shells treat `"$@"` specially, see section "Special Parameters" in the Bash manpage.